# Access hardware buttons (like the volume buttons) from Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am building an app that would act as a remote for presentations. I would like to use the volume buttons to trigger some sort of event. Can I capture hardware button clicks in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New plugin called [Hardware Buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) was released, which supports detecting volume button events.

You may have a go with that!

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin has significant limitations. On Android it requires specific permission to use volume buttons (which native apps do not do). On iOS it ignores volume down button if your volume is at minimum, and up button if your volume is at maximum. For my projects such limitations were unacceptable. (Plus the plugin hasn't been updated for 2 years, so I do not recommend using it).

Answer (score 0):

You have two option.

1. Use Platform channels .This is avails more options to you but will involve writing java/kotlin code
2. At pub.dartlang.org/packages there are packages such as system_shortcuts 0.1.0
   or flutter_lock_screen which you check to see if they can fulfill your needs.